# Accessing apache2 residing inside Docker container from Host machine web browser

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, docker, boot2docker

I have been creating a webserver as Docker container and trying to access it outside the container. But I can't. What I am doing is.

-Pulling a ubuntu image:

```
docker pull ubuntu:14.04
```

-Starting a container:

```
docker -t -i -p 49200:2375 [image-id]
```

and after installing apache2 in newly started container I can ping the apache2 server inside container, I can also do curl and see results in container terminal, but no luck outside on host machine. I have tried many times. (I am using Virtual Box on windows)

Screen shots:

[image: docker 1]

[image: docker 2]

Questions:

1. Am I using right docker commands and port numbers to create container.
2. Is there anything wrong in apache configuration. (I am using apache in default mode without any configurations)
3. Is there anything wrong with ports on my virtual box or on my pc. I have very low knowledge of networking.

Can someone help!!!

Comment: Apache normally serves file on port 80. You haven't exposed this in a port mapping. Maybe it's not that simple...

Comment: Thanks for reply. So, Are you saying, I need to expose port 80 from docker container, and have to add port 80 in Virtual box as well.

Comment: after adding port 80 in Virtual Box, and mapping that port on Docker containe, I can get results in my browser, but with this ip 127.0.0.1, and not with 172.17.0.7. Can you please explain why its not accessible at 172.17.0.7

Comment: Virtual environment within a virtual environment. 172.17.0.7 is the network interface of the linux OS virtualbox is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1**: Apache default port

`2375` port is not the apache default port, it is the docker daemon default port, the command shall be

```
docker -t -i -p 49200:80 [image-id]
```

**Problem 2**: port in different machine

`49200:80` This is the mapping from internal port `80` to **docker host** `49200`, the docker host is actually your virtual box VM (guess is your boot2docker shell)

In your virtual box VM console, you can

```
curl localhost:49200
```

The picture "Port Forwarding rules" are helping your port forward to your virtualbox host, for you it is MacOS, where you mapped `49200` to MacOS `49200` as well

So in your MacOS shell console, you can also

```
curl localhost:49200
```

If you know the virtualbox VM (docker host) IP address, for example it is `192.168.59.103` as default for boot2docker, then you can

```
curl 192.168.59.103:49200
```

If you want to access the apache docker container via `172.17.0.7`, remember this is the private network inside, you need to start another container like

```
docker -t -i busybox bash
# curl 172.17.0.7:80
```

### Summary

`docker -p` is port forwarding your internal port to docker host
"Port forwarding Rules" in virtualbox setting is port forwarding your VM port to VM host

- apache docker container: 172.17.0.7:80
- docker host=virtualbox VM: 192.168.59.103:49200
- virtualbox host=MacOS: xxxx:49200